# Linking to answers - possible "self promotion"?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, best-practices, self-promotion

Let's say a new question is posted, and I've answered that question before in depth. If I link to my answer in my comment, would that be considered "promoting" that answer - an attempt to gain more upvotes for that answer? Is it acceptable, or would I receive criticism for doing so, even though it was unintentional?

Comment: That's okay. Just don't overdo it.

Comment: Linking to anywhere is allowed in comment, except for blatant advertisement/spam/malware.

Comment: Why wouldn't you mark the question as a duplicate?

Comment: @AlEverett good point. Sometimes, however, the question is not an exact dupe, but the answer still applies. In those situations I might add a comment, instead of voting to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is it acceptable to linking our answer?

Yes it is acceptable. It is not considered as self promoting for upvotes. If you think the question is same then you can close/flag the question as a duplicate.

> Would that be considered "promoting" that answer?

No. In fact it is considered a good behavior for not posting the same answer twice.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!