# Flagging "look at my answer pls" comments

Tags: discussion, comments, comment-flags

I've started to flag a few of these once I had seen one too many of them, but I'm not sure whether I'm doing the right thing.  This is an example of what I'm talking about (this comment is on the question, but sometimes on their own answers too):

[image]

Are they something that should be considered acceptable, and if not, are they bad enough to be "flaggable"?

Comment: I find such comments useless and borderline "rep-whoring"

Comment: Are these comments pointing to answers on the same question or on a different question?

Comment: @AndersUP: the same question, if it was a different question I would consider that worse.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy - If it is on a different question and you think the OP can get his solution from your answer then it is [*worth*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180487/187824) to mention it. (also you should vote/flag to close.)

Comment: Agree with @hims056 - on the same question it would usually be bad, but on a different question it might be relevant. I have to admit I do it frequently with both questions and answers (not always my own) that might bring perspective to a question. Primarily here on Meta, though, and rarely (if ever) on the same question. Never in the form you describe in your question.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy, Also see http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253833/should-we-flag-look-at-my-answer-comments

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you posted your answer, somebody is bound to see it. There isn't much of a point announcing your answer, it just creates a needless distraction *before* someone even gets a chance to see your answer, and at worst it'll even discourage someone from looking at your answer (for reasons like what Da_smokes said, they smell like rep-whoring).

You can flag such comments as not constructive or too chatty.

I do post such a comment if I think I have a good reason to call attention to my answer, for instance if I believe the existing answers are misleading or wrong despite having received upvotes:

> Note that many of the answers here miss a certain important point [explain what that point is], which I've addressed in an answer of my own.

but that doesn't mean if I don't comment, nobody will see my answer.

At the end of the day, it's all about whether a comment adds any useful information to the topic at hand. If it doesn't, it's noise and it doesn't need to be there.

Comment: Indeed, a link eo ipso *may* add useful information to the topic at hand, even without the introductory abstract *"Note that many of the answers here miss a certain important point [explain what that point is], which I've addressed in an answer of my own."*

Comment: A link to what, exactly?

Comment: A link to an answer that addresses why many of the other answers there miss a certain important point and what that point is.

Comment: Like "See my answer: [link]"? That gives the exact same impression we want to avoid.

Comment: Hmm, ["impression"](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+impression)? Do you mean *feeling* / *opinion*? No, I'd thought we were talking about "information". "At the end of the day, it's all about whether a comment adds any useful information to the topic at hand." It's all about whether the reader will benefit from clicking that link. Indeed, my point is what's important is the *content* of the link, not how the introductory abstract is *phrased*. I have personally benefited from many comments that were simply "[link]" or "See [link]" or "Also see [link]".