# Comments to make the answer more visible

Tags: discussion, comments, answers, visibility

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19651860/2024761). It has 4 answers, out of which 1 is deleted and another one has been posted by me. There is another answer which was posted a minute later after my answer.

Since I posted the answer a minute earlier and thus I got the early upvotes. The answer didn't get as many upvotes as mine. I'm really not sure if that is the reason, but the OP of that other answer seems to be commenting everywhere to get his answer noticed. Have a look at these comments. [Comment 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651860/why-is-printed-1#comment29180627_19651860),  [Comment 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651860/why-is-printed-1#comment29180745_19651870) &  [Comment 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19651860/why-is-printed-1#comment29180777_19651876).

I'm sure that the other answer is equally good as mine, or may be better also, but does it mean we should go around posting comments to the OP to get our answers noticed? Is it a good practice? Because I feel that as you've already posted the answer, the OP(and the other users) are bound to see that and if they feel its really helpful, they would certainly go ahead and upvote it so that its visible at the top. There really isn't any need to keep posting comments to get your answer noticed. Am I right about this?! Or getting our answers more visibility by comments everywhere is a practice followed on Stack Overflow(and if it, I really don't feel its nice).

Comment: Maybe the first comment you linked to is a bit over the line, but the other two were contesting the correctness of an answer and answering a question on the poster's own answer. Am I missing something?

Comment: @CarlVeazey - I just mentioned them. I feel the 3rd comment is fine as it was posted on the poster's own answer. And the 2nd comment was actually posted on my answer and not the poster's answer.

Comment: @hims056 - Your search query was better than mine. I has searched for *answer more visible* on Meta, but did not get any proper hits. Hence, posted this question. I don't mind this getting closed now as a duplicate!:)

Comment: @R.J - Actually I didn't search. I already [knew](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/202109/flagging-look-at-my-answer-pls-comments#comment642341_202109 "Knew because I have commented there.") that question. :)

Comment: @hims056 - I read the answer there. Its good, but then it doesn't say what needs to be done in such a scenario. Do we tell the poster to not do that, or flag the comments, or something(these are just examples, not saying we should do this). Anything we could do to counter this and may be make aware everybody to refrain from such a behavior?!

Comment: @R.J - "You can flag such comments as not constructive or too chatty." Didn't you read it?

Comment: @hims056 - Missed that! Thanks again!:)